# NSArray copy for undo /redo purposes

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

If I have an nsarray full of custom objects and I make a second array using:

```
NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithArray:original];
```

then work with some properties of the objects inside the original array, then decide to roll back, I am then using the reverse:

```
original = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
```

I am finding the objects I changed in the array also effected my temp array.  I also tried implementing copyWithZone on my custom class, and using copyItems and it did not help.  What else should I try?

To be clear, in order to use copyWithZone, I changed my array creation command to:

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:original copyItems:YES];
```

My copyWithZone:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    CustomObject *ret = [[CustomObject allocWithZone: zone] init];
    //copy properties
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure the `copyWithZone:` is called?

Comment: What does your `copyWithZone:` implementation look like?

Comment: added the basic code for this, and  yes it is being called, I set breakpoints to be sure'

Comment: Thanks for updates. Now when you log contents of these two arrays, the objects (addresses) must be different in each of them. What modifications do you do on them?

Comment: Maybe more of you code would help. More context. Are you storing them only in local variables or in properties?

Comment: Different memory addresses - still debugging here

Comment: OK, it seems to work better if I use copyItems going both ways...

Comment: Doing undo should be simple as `original = temp;`. There must be something else going on.

Comment: oddly enough, if the only change is the undo code, it stops working

Comment: What means "work with some properties"? Maybe you have retain (strong, not copy) property of some mutable type (NSMutableDictionary for example) and change instance of this type. Something like:`myObj.dict = myDict; myObj2.dict = myDict; [myObj1.dict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"]; //now myObj2.dict is also changed because there are only one object realy and two pointers to it`

Comment: I am modifying a CMTime property, which is set as assign

Comment: In `//copy properties` are you copying any mutable values without making new copies?

Comment: the one property that I am changing is a CMTime property, and on the copyWithZone I am making a new one from scratch by converting to seconds and then back to CMTime

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard.  Figure out which values are not being properly preserved, and study how you copy them.  Also check that you're not overwriting the values due to a finger check elsewhere.

Comment: totally unrelated to NSArray, have you consider to use NSUndoManager?